# Error while signing ethereum transaction with Private key and Infura URL

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, tokens, ethereumjs-tx

Unable to decode sender address from transaction: Incompatible EIP155-based V 37 and chain id 3. See the Common parameter of the Transaction constructor to set the chain id

Please suggest me where i am doing wrong?

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddr).then(count => {
  var rawTransaction = {
    "from": fromAddr,
    "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(count),
    "gasPrice":web3.utils.toHex(100000000000),
    "gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex(4712388),
    "to": contract_addr,
    "value": "0x0",
    "data": contract.methods.transfer(_address, _value).encodeABI(),
    "chainId": 3
};

var privKey = new Buffer.from('my account private key', 'hex');
var tx = new TX(rawTransaction);

tx.sign(privKey);
var serializedTx = tx.serialize();

web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
    if (!err)
    res.status(203).json({hash:hash});
    else
        
        res.status(400).json({ err : err.message+" "+count+" "+fromAddr+" "+_value});
}); 
});


} catch(error) {
    res.status(400).json({ message : error.message});
}
```

Comment: solved the problem with small change in code, just remove the chain id from raw transaction and add it to Tx object like   var tx = new TX(rawTransaction, {'chain':'ropsten'});

Comment: this solution worked for me too, but for Rinkeby testnet and Alchemy (swapped "ropsten" with "rinkeby"). Thank you!! Only solution I could find online.

Comment: @nania It would be nice if you can add the change you made as the answer so the question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Updated code as follows:

```
web3.eth.getTransactionCount(fromAddr).then(count => {
    var rawTransaction = {
      "from": fromAddr,
      "nonce": web3.utils.toHex(count+1),
      "gasPrice":web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
      "gasLimit":web3.utils.toHex(52821),
      "to": addr,
      "value": "0x0",
      "data": contract.methods.transfer(_addr, _value).encodeABI()
    
  };
  
  var privKey = new Buffer.from('Private key', 'hex');
  var tx = new TX(rawTransaction, {'chain':'ropsten'});
  
  tx.sign(privKey);
  var serializedTx = tx.serialize();
  
  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx.toString('hex'), function(err, hash) {
      if (!err)
      res.status(203).json({hash:hash});
      else
          //console.log(err);
          res.status(400).json({ err : err.message+" "+count+" "+fromAddr+" "+_value});
  }); 
  });
```